# Data extension update with journey builder

Tags: dataextensions

Can we update Data extension with the help of jouney builder ?

Detail- I have a journey builder in which i want if email will be sent out to the subscriber the their will be check box or boolean field which will automatically update ?

IS it possible ? If yes, then how ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as long as your contact model is set up correctly, you can use the 'Update Contact' activity in Journey Builder to update an associated data extension.

For most of my journeys, I have a 'Log' DE that I store every contact who enters into, and use the 'Update Contact' activity to create an audit trail of every contact that's gone through the journey so I can see who is currently active, who received which emails, etc. This was the recommended approach from SFMC Pro Services when I engaged them a while back.

So my steps are basically:

1) Run query to grab all contacts that should enter the journey today, ADD to Journey_Log DE.

2) Run same query, and OVERWRITE Journey_Live DE. This will be the Journey entry source.

3) Journey triggers when Journey_Live DE is changed via automation studio.

As contacts progress through the journey, I am constantly updating boolean flags on their record in my log with things like:

- Active Journey
- Received Email 1
- Opened Email 1
- Redeemed Offer
- etc.

Hope that helps a bit in answering your question.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on point 3. How do you configure your journey so it triggers when it changes?

Also, when you write "ADD" in point 1, you mean Update the data extension, right? (the three options for a DE being append, update and overwrite)

Comment: @RamonMartinez `Journey_Live` is the Data Extension Entry Source for the journey. If you schedule the journey to run based on the automation that populates `Journey_Live`, when you activate the journey it will create an event that fires at the end of your automation, which adds all the contacts in Journey_Live to the journey.

In point 1, I usually overwrite my journey entry source (Journey_Live), but you could also simply add new records and set your journey to only evaluate new records.

Hope this helps.